# How do you upload a file to a pre-signed POST URL from a browser to Minio or S3 using javascript

Tags: amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, axios, superagent, minio

[This article](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/) shows how to upload a file to Amazon S3 or minio using a form.  I want to use the pre-signed POST URL policy method, since it appears to be the most secure.

However, I wish to upload a file programmatically to minio or S3 using a browser.  In other words, I want to use javascript, not a form.

I'm a node user and familiar with [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests), which is very simple to use using the `.field()` and `.attach()` operation to set the form fields and to upload the file.

This works in node:

```
  let cdnAgent = superagent;
  let req = cdnAgent.post(r.data.pictureSet.uploadLink);
  _.each(uploadForm, function(value, key) {
    req.field(key, value);
  });
  // upload file via the created signed policy
  return req
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
  .attach('file', 'test/data/test.jpg');
}).then(r => {
```

However, this does not work in a browser, `.attach()` is not supported, and when I worked around that, I ran into CORS issues since my javascript domain is a separate domain from my minio or S3 domain.

To answer this question I'd like to see a complete example using XMLHttpRequest, Axios, superagent, or Fetch, that works across domains.

I note there are some similar questions to this and some answers, but they all appear to be very outdated and technology has moved on. So I don't think this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Buckets support [custom CORS responses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html), so you should be able to work around that part of the issue.

Comment: CORS is on by default on minio, which is what I was testing against.  But thanks for the Amazon CORS link, I'll probably need that at some point.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had S3 on the brain and completely glossed over the multiple mentions of minio.

Comment: BTW Superagent does work, however it just provides a very confusing CORS message if you get anything wrong.  Thread here with working code at the bottom.  https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/1193

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/harshavardhana/minio-js-browser-upload/ you can simply clone this repo and then run

```
node presign-post-server.js
```

Visit browser at http://localhost:8080. Click on the upload file and just upload the selected file will be uploaded through presigned post policy style. [1]

Currently the example just points to https://play.minio.io:9000 and to `uploads` bucket. [2]

[1] https://github.com/harshavardhana/minio-js-browser-upload/blob/master/index-post.html

[2] https://github.com/harshavardhana/minio-js-browser-upload/blob/master/presign-post-server.js

Comment: working example, love it!.  Now just package it in a docker image :-).  But seriously thanks, this is a canonical XMLHttpRequest example.  SuperAgent answer in comments in OP.  Now someone just needs to post the Axios answer and the next noob will be better off...